# TestCafe & chrome:headless : how to force the browser language (locale)

Tags: npm, internationalization, e2e-testing, google-chrome-headless, testcafe

I have write a few browser test who run with TestCafe, chrome:headless. The test are launched by commandline, from a server that I don't want to change the default language.

My website is multi-language. I want to be change the language of the test, without having to impact the language of the server/computer each time. How can I do that?

I launch the tests with this command line:

```
npx testcafe chrome:headless src/scenarios/**/*.test.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your "multi-language" implementation:

1. [Navigate to](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/navigate.html) some "locale" page version (example.com/**en/**).
2. Start your tests from a landing page and then navigate to the specific "locale" version:

```js
await t
    .click(Selector('#choose-lang-combo')
    .click(Selector('#en-lang'))
```

3. Try to [add](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/creating-a-custom-http-request-hook.html#the-onrequest-method) your own [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header to your request.
4. Use a [custom user profile](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n). **Maybe just using the `--lang` flag (`testcafe chrome --lang=es`) will help you (without the custom user profile)**:

> For example, to create a shortcut that launches Google Chrome in Spanish (es), you might create a shortcut named chrome-es that has the following target:`path_to_chrome.exe --lang=es --user-data-dir=c:\chrome-profile-es`