# TestCafe headless localization parameters

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am writing a fixture, and multiple tests assert the page's title to be some value. However, I did not account for the fact that the website is localized. My normal browser settings are English, but when I run the `testcafe chrome:headless myTests.js` my tests fails because the Localization changes, perhaps due to my PC's language?

I have tried running my local chrome installation and adding `:userProfile`, but without luck sadly.

The only other information I can find regarding this issue is, but I can't make it work:

- [TestCafe & chrome:headless : how to force the browser language (locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076377/testcafe-chromeheadless-how-to-force-the-browser-language-locale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405790/run-testcafe-headless-when-passing-custom-args-to-chrome-binary-via-testcafe-bro) - go give them a like if it solves your issue as well.

**Solution:**

I use the following command to launch chrome headless with a locale specified:

`testcafe chrome:headless --lang=en-US`